# Getting rid of lag time when playing sound with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to play sounds with a .keydown() event in jQuery. I would like the sounds to play quickly, but there seems to be a lag time when I perform the keydown event faster than about 3 times per second.

Here is a jsFiddle of my sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/pfrater/FRudg/3/

I am using the audio html tags for the sound and playing:

```
<audio controls id="sound" preload="auto"> 
<source src="http://www.wavlist.com/soundfx/011/duck-baby.wav" type="audio/wav"/> 
</audio>

<audio controls id="sound2" preload="auto"> 
<source src="http://rezound.sourceforge.net/examples/chirp.wav" type="audio/wav"/> 
</audio>

<audio controls id="sound3" preload="auto"> 
<source src="http://www.all-birds.com/Sound/downychirp.wav" type="audio/wav"/> 
</audio>
```

and here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
var playing;
$(document).bind("keydown", function(key) {
    playing = undefined;
    switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
        case 65:
            playing = $("#sound").get(0);
            break;
        case 83:
            playing = $("#sound2").get(0);
            break;
        case 68:
            playing = $("#sound3").get(0);
            break;
     };
     if (playing) {
        playing.play();
     }
  }).on("keyup", function() {
    if(playing){
        playing.pause();
        playing.currentTime=50;
        playing = undefined;
     }
  });
});
```

Does anyone know of a way to get rid of this lag? Also, the actual files that I'll be playing are mpegs. The ones above are just an example.

Thanks for any help,
Paul

Comment: what browser? I am testing this on a crappy windows machine with chrome and it is fine.

Comment: @Paul it works here also, just fine.

Comment: I am using Safari. Yes, it plays the sound just fine, but I want it to go faster. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this with the audio element. This is because the cost setting up and filling the buffers will take too much time.

The good news though is that you can do it using the **[Web Audio API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/)** instead.

I made you an example based on [this code from HTML5 rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/) (which you should check out for more details) and your original fiddle.

Currently this API is [supported in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api) will be able to use this:

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/y491bbt0/)**

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

/// custom buffer loader
/// see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/
function BufferLoader(context, urlList, callback) {
    this.context = context;
    this.urlList = urlList;
    this.onload = callback;
    this.bufferList = new Array();
    this.loadCount = 0;
}

BufferLoader.prototype.loadBuffer = function (url, index) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    var loader = this;

    request.onload = function () {
        // Asynchronously decode the audio file data in request.response
        loader.context.decodeAudioData(
        request.response,

        function (buffer) {
            if (!buffer) {
                alert('error decoding file data: ' + url);
                return;
            }
            loader.bufferList[index] = buffer;
            if (++loader.loadCount == loader.urlList.length)
                loader.onload(loader.bufferList);
        },

        function (error) {
            console.error('decodeAudioData error', error);
        });
    }

    request.onerror = function (e) {
        alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');
    }    
    request.send();
}

BufferLoader.prototype.load = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.urlList.length; ++i)
    this.loadBuffer(this.urlList[i], i);
}
```

The main code:

```
/// setup audio context and start loading samples
var actx = new AudioContext(),
    blst,
    bLoader = new BufferLoader(
    actx, [
        'duck-baby.wav', 'chirp.wav', 'downychirp.wav'],
    done),
    isReady = false;

/// start loading the samples
bLoader.load();

function done(bl) {
    blst = bl;                           /// buffer list
    isReady = true;                      /// enable keys
    $('#status').html('Ready!');         /// update statusw
}

/// this sets up chain so we can play audio
function play(i) {
    var src = actx.createBufferSource(); /// prepare sample
    src.buffer = blst[i];                /// set buffer from loader
    src.connect(actx.destination);       /// connect to speakers
    src.start(0);                        /// play sample now
}

/// check keys
$(window).bind("keydown", function (key) {
    if (!isReady) return;
    switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
        case 65:
            play(0);
            return;
        case 83:
            play(1);
            return;
        case 68:
            play(2);
            return;
    }    
})
```

**NOTE:** When using external samples you must make sure they can be used cross-origin or else loading will fail (I used my DropBox to enable the samples to be loaded with fiddle).